# Return custom columns in Rails ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am querying my ActiveRecords in rails with the following:

```
result = MyObj.where({customer: current_id}).as_json()
```

There are two columns returned:

```
result = [{id:1, name: "david", last_name: "Smith:"}]
```

I would like create a third column (which will not be saved to the DB) like so:

```
result = [{id:1, name: "David", last_name: "Smith:", full_name:"David Smith"}]
```

Is this possible within the WHERE query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `full_name` method to your MyObj model, then pass `methods: :full_name` to the `as_json` method:

```
class MyObj
  def full_name
    "{name} #{last_name}"
  end
end

result = MyObj.where({customer: current_id}).as_json(methods: :full_name)
```

From [the documentation for `as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json):

> To include the result of some method calls on the model use :methods:
>
> ```
> user.as_json(methods: :permalink)
> # => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
> #      "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true,
> #      "permalink" => "1-konata-izumi" }
> ```

Or alternately, you could override `as_json` on the model to include `full_name` by default:

```
class MyObj
  def full_name
    "{name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def as_json(options={})
    super({methods: :full_name}.merge options)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Override the method in your model...

```
class MyObj < ActiveRecord::Base

  def full_name
    "#{name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def as_json options={}
    {
      id: id,
      name: name,
      last_name: last_name,
      full_name: full_name
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty just manipulate the results you get back

```
result = MyObj.where({customer: current_id})
result.map{|customer| "full_name: #{customer.first_name + customer.last_name}" }
```

But be careful of nil values.